# Runtime permission dialogue does not appear for SMS read

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to request to Read permission but system permission dialogue does not appear. When I added the SMS Receive permission then dialogue appears but why it does not work on only SMS Read permission?

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, 101);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                101);
    } else {
        Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED");
    }
```

Also make sure you have to add permission in `Manifest`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```